# Node raspberry websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, raspberry-pi, cluster

Node.js. Запущен на Raspberrypi .Слушается порядка 20 websocket'ов.
Каждое сообщение, соответственно обрабатывается. 
При этом статистика выводится через поднятый там же сервер.
Проблема: при прослушке websocket'ов, ресурсов на свой сервер не остается и страница "висит".
Мониторинг показал переодические скачки к 100% загрузке одного из 4х ядер малинки.
Видится причина в этом. Надо разгрузить.
Возможно следует поднять свой сервер через кластер. Но тут 1 вопрос:
*Есть вариант оставить общий namespace для всех форков или 
их все же надо связывать через месенджи с главным процессом?
Тут же еще момент: даже если "форкопроизводство" находится в подключаемом модуле, 
оно все равно дублирует родительский модуль по запущенным функциям - не порядок.
Вариант 2: раскидать прослушку сокетов по ядрам, пусть хватает первый свободный.
Но вопросы про namespace так же актуален.
Нода поднятая на i7 потребляет 1-3% ресурсов проца.
Мониторинг малинки показывает 120-260 мб памяти и 20-30% проца(суммарно), 
по ядру же регулярные скачки до 100%.
Спасибо.

Comment: да проще нормальную современную плату взять, чем кластер городить  - ODROID XU4, ASUS Tinker - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers

Comment: Ну, тут речь идет о кластере между ядрами проца, а не аппаратной сборке. Да, запустить можно и на других машинах - такой проблемы не будет. Но 5v потребление и тишина соблазняют. Да и дальнейшее расширение будет за рамки одного ядра.

Comment: сама плата и есть кластер между ядрами проца )) если плата + ОС с задачей дистрибуции ресурсов не справляется, можно либо найти и устранить причину настройкой параметров ОС, либо же только усугубить проблему установкой дополнительного ПО, которое создаст еще большую нагрузку на ядра и ОС

Comment: на ODROID есть бесшумный радиатор, и разница в цене не очень существенная если ODRIOD конфигурировать по минимуму, без eMMC

Comment: у Node.js есть метод кластеризации, который распределяет трафик по ядрам, так как изначально она грузит только одно. И вопрос скорее в этой плоскости. Так как вариант "купить другое", конечно имеет право на жизнь, но хуже масштабируется и требует гораздо больше времени реализации.

Comment: Оч хорошая статья - https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-nginx-node-js-and-networking-for-heavy-workloads